# Variadic function wont compile with clang

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer

First off, I apologize if this is a duplicate, I will be happy to take it down but I am not even sure what the issue/diagnosis is here.

Anyway, my code here works with gcc and not clang - why is this the case? I am clearly not able to understand why clang cant compile this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


template <typename T, typename... Args, typename std::enable_if<!sizeof...(Args)>::type* = nullptr>
void func(int start_size, int idx)
{
    cout << start_size << " " << idx << endl;
    return;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args, typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args)>::type* = nullptr>
void func(int start_size, int idx)
{

    if((idx + 1) == int(start_size - int(sizeof...(Args))))
       {
           cout << start_size << " " << idx << endl;
           return;
       }
       func<Args...>(start_size, idx);
}

template <typename... Args>
void func_wrapper(int idx)
{
    func<Args...>(sizeof...(Args),idx);
}


int main()
{
    func_wrapper<int,double,char>(1);

}
```

Error:

```
prog.cc:37:5: error: no matching function for call to 'func'
    func<Args...>(sizeof...(Args),idx);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:44:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'func_wrapper<int, double, char>' requested here
    func_wrapper<int,double,char>(1);
    ^
prog.cc:16:6: note: candidate template ignored: requirement '!sizeof...(Args)' was not satisfied [with T = int, Args = <double, char>]
void func(int start_size, int idx)
     ^
prog.cc:23:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = int, Args = <double, char>]: non-type template argument evaluates to 2, which cannot be narrowed to type 'bool'
void func(int start_size, int idx)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Wandbox: https://wandbox.org/permlink/yqki47uYcwUlE013

Answer (score 7, accepted):

clang is correct in rejecting this code. To eliminate the error, you should explicitly apply a conversion:

```
std::enable_if<bool(sizeof...(Args))>
```

The reasoning is:

[[temp.arg.nontype]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.arg.nontype#5)

> The following conversions are performed on each expression used as a
>   non-type template-argument. If a non-type template-argument cannot be
>   converted to the type of the corresponding template-parameter then the
>   program is ill-formed.
>
> (5.1) For a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration
>   type, **conversions permitted in a converted constant expression
>   ([expr.const]) are applied**.

Then [[expr.const]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.const#3) says that a narrowing conversion is not considered automatically:

> A converted constant expression of type T is a literal constant
>   expression, implicitly converted to type T, where the implicit
>   conversion (if any) is permitted in a literal constant expression and
>   the implicit conversion sequence contains only user-defined
>   conversions, lvalue-to-rvalue conversions ([conv.lval]), integral
>   promotions ([conv.prom]), and **integral conversions ([conv.integral])
>   other than narrowing conversions** ([dcl.init.list])

Thus for this case, a narrowing conversion from `std::size_t` to `bool`, it should be explicit: `bool(sizeof...(Args))`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! How did you know exactly where to look in the standard? I've always wanted to be able to do that...

Comment: @PYA You can check the contents directory first. The related sections are usually visible from the catalog. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/#temp

Comment: Better yet: `enable_if<sizeof...(Args)!=0>`

Comment: @PYA looking up the Standard is a skill you'll acquire by trying and failing. Keep trying ;) soon there will be part of it where you could feel if an answer could hide in or not.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of the missing explicit conversion from `std::size_t` to `bool` which would require code as

```
std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) != 0>
```

There is an other error:

[temp#res-8.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8.3)

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> [..]
>
> every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack,

So

```
template <typename T,
          typename... Args,
          typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) == 0>::type* = nullptr>
```

is invalid.
(There is also `void* = nullptr` which might be problematic).

You may write it with 2 overloads instead:

```
template <typename T>
void func(int start_size, int idx)
{
    cout << start_size << " " << idx << endl;
}

template <typename T, typename T2, typename... Args> // Addition of T2, and change sizeof...
void func(int start_size, int idx)
{
    if ((idx + 1) == int(start_size - int(1 + sizeof...(Args)))) {
        cout << start_size << " " << idx << endl;
        return;
    }
    func<T2, Args...>(start_size, idx);
}
```

Comment: That statement in standard is surprising. Is there any particular reason to single out this case and mark it as *ill-formed*? I don't think "every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack" is a special case that should be treated differently.

Comment: @liliscent: I don't know the reason behind. A warning would make sense as, indeed, it is useless (but it is complicated to identify in generic case). But then warning would also been fine for case when it is necessary one type (as then we might replace it by single `typename T`).

Comment: I couldn't find meaningful explanation of that rule either, though there are a couple of SO questions related. BTW, I don't think it applies here, since we can specialize `typename T` and remain `typename... Args` intact. This is a specialization without introducing an empty pack.